# problem deleting shapefiles because still in use by arcpy cursor

Tags: python, arcpy, parallel-processing

I have a function `outputTblContents` which contains

```
def outputTblContents ( path ):
    rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(path, fields="alpha; beta")
    for row in rows:
        print("{0} => {1}").format(row.getValue("alpha"), row.getValue("beta"))
```

The function that called `outputTblContents` then tries to delete the folder that `path` is in, but is unable to because it’s still in use by the script. I guess arcpy.SearchCursor spawns it’s own thread. How do I wait for it to be finished so I can safely delete the shapefiles and clean up?

```
outputTblContents(pathToShpfile)
shutil.rmtree(pathToTempDir)
```

Here is the error
WindowsError: `[Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: '\\\\storage1\\gis\\dev\\temp\\ collated_a1.shp….sr.lock'`

Comment: Not quite. That one is ArcObjects. Try this one http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148828/python-script-working-incorrectly/148860#148860 when using an arcpy.SearchCursor (or insert or update) you must del the cursor to release the lock. Read the answer Celeritas, there's a few good hints there.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson what exactly does mean "cursor"?

Comment: if rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(pa.. rows is a cursor http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z0000009r000000 with for row in rows: row is a row http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z0000008r000000 both need to be released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're script above probably still has a lock onto the data.
Specifically this line:

```
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(path, fields="alpha; beta")
```

You've got two ways to get around the lock.

Delete the rows variable after your loop

```
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(path, fields="alpha; beta")
for row in rows:
    print("{0} => {1}").format(row.getValue("alpha"), row.getValue("beta"))
del rows
```

Or you can call the search cursor within a **with** block. Doing this will let python release the object when the with block completes. In your case, when the for row in rows completes

```
with arcpy.SearchCursor(path, fields="alpha; beta") as rows:
    for row in rows:
        print("{0} => {1}").format(row.getValue("alpha"), row.getValue("beta"))
```

Edit:
Here is the arcpy.da.SearchCursor example

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(path,["alpha","beta"]) as rows:
    for row in rows:
        print("{} => {}".format(row[0],row[1]))
```

Comment: Also, check out the arcpy.da search cursors.
ESRI considers the non-da ones to be legacy from 10.1 onwards. 
Heres a link for more information:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z0000001q000000

Comment: with the `with` statement I'm getting `AttributeError: __exit__`

Comment: I added an example for the arcpy.da one. see if that works

Comment: What version of Arc are you running? arcpy.da is not available before 10.1; might be the same for the with statement.

Comment: I have Arcmap 10.2.1 installed. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Says `undefined variable from import: SearchCursor`

Comment: Have you imported arcpy?

Comment: @Cody yes...the program actually works but it looks like the IDE is giving a false error.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Send me a message if you run into any more trouble with it!

Comment: @Cody, arcpy.SearchCursor does not support *with*, only arcpy.da.SearchCursor supports the use of *with*, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148828/python-script-working-incorrectly/148860#148860 (paragraph after first code block)